# RxSwift validation button color is not set properly

Tags: ios, swift, validation, rx-swift

I'm using RxSwift to validate input from user, if everything is valid I want to enable a button and change its color. In my button class I have created `Variable<Bool>`:

```
var valid = Variable(false)
```

In `initWithCoder` I'm doing such thing:

```
valid.asObservable()
    .subscribe(onNext:  { [weak self] valid in
        self?.isEnabled = valid
        self?.titleLabel?.textColor = valid ? .white : .black
    })
    .addDisposableTo(disposeBag)
```

I have a method that validates input and returns an `Observable<Bool>` called `validateDate()` (I won't post it here for brevity):

```
let dataValid = viewModel.validateData()

dataValid
    .bind(to: submitButton.valid)
    .addDisposableTo(disposeBag)
```

The problem is, that although the `valid` value in subscription is correct and enabling button works perfectly, setting button's color does not work properly, because it seems like it changes color on next emission, not when valid became `true`.

Am I doing something wrong here? I would be thankful for any help.

Comment: are you changing the colour on the main thread?

Comment: I tried adding .observeOn(MainScheduler.instance) before .subscribe, but it did not help.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Have you tried `setTitleColor` to change button's title color?

You might consider using `UIBindingObserver` for UI bindings:

```
import PlaygroundSupport
import UIKit
import RxSwift
import RxCocoa

extension Reactive where Base: UIButton {

    var valid: AnyObserver<Bool> {
        return UIBindingObserver(UIElement: base, binding: { (button: UIButton, valid: Bool) in
            button.isEnabled = valid
            button.setTitleColor(valid ? .white : .black, for: .normal)
        }).asObserver()
    }
}

let button = UIButton()
button.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 100, height: 50)
button.backgroundColor = UIColor.orange
button.setTitle("Title", for: .normal)
Observable<Int>
    .timer(0, period: 1, scheduler: MainScheduler.instance)
    .map({ $0 % 2 == 0})
    .bind(to: button.rx.valid)

PlaygroundPage.current.liveView = button
```

Answer (score 4):

**Swift 4, RxCocoa 4** has now dropped UIBindingObserver in favour of Binder

```
extension Reactive where Base : UIButton {
   public var valid : Binder<Bool> {
        return Binder(self.base) { button, valid in
            button.isEnabled = valid
            button.setTitleColor(valid ? .white : .black, for: .normal)
        }
    }
}
```